# PostgreSQL & JDBC set array of ints using `setArray` throw an exception "cannot cast type integer[] to integer"

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

How do I set an array of integers in JDBC (prepared statement with `setArray` for an in clause?

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (?)";
// other things.
// ArrayList<Integer> some_ids;
preparedStatement.setArray(1, conn.createArrayOf("INTEGER", some_ids.toArray()));
```

It compiles, but executing returns this from Postgres.

```
ERROR: cannot cast type integer[] to integer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PostgreSQL You have to use `= ANY(?)` instead of `IN (?)`

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ANY(?)";
```

Take a look at this : [9.21.3. ANY/SOME (array)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparisons.html)